# Create user and revoke them access to a specific database on MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

Is there an easy way to create a user and grant all privileges to all databases except a specific one?

I've tried this

```
CREATE USER 'demo'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'QbSv9qUj2EJ8mxm2';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'demo'@'%';
REVOKE ALL ON id8694160_sqless.* FROM 'demo'@'%'; -- this is the DB I don't want the user to have access to
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'demo'@'%';
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1141. There is no such grant defined for user 'demo' on host '%'
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: i would advice you to be more "accurate" with the privileges you give.. You are "blindly" running `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'demo'@'%';` with more accurate i mean `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database1.* TO 'demo'@'%';`  `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database2.* TO 'demo'@'%';`  Also using some SQL IDE like "SQLYog community" would make it more easy as you can simply "click".

Comment: Also you should change you password right now as you just shared it on the internet..

Comment: Revoking only removes given priveledges (and granting wildcard images does only add the wildcard priveledge and not multiple specific priveledges which can be revoked).

Comment: @RaymondNijland don't worry, this is a randomly generated password I used for the question.

Comment: fair enough i don't worry as it's is your password and your MySQL account..

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/grant/#privilege-levels):

> **Global privileges** are granted using *.* for priv_level. Global privileges include privileges to administer the database and manage user accounts, as well as privileges for all tables, functions, and procedures. **Global privileges are stored in the mysql.user table.**
>
> **Database privileges** are granted using db_name.* for priv_level, or using just * to use default database. Database privileges include privileges to create tables and functions, as well as privileges for all tables, functions, and procedures in the database. **Database privileges are stored in the mysql.db table.**

It means that the privileges you grant with `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'demo'@'%';` is represented by one row in the mysql.user table. Revoking privileges for only one database from these global privileges means removing the global privileges from the mysql.user table and add one database privilege for each database except the id8694160_sqless database, in the mysql.db table.

I'm quite sure the `REVOKE` statement does not do this but you can manually give privileges to all databases except one with a request such as :

```
INSERT INTO mysql.db
SELECT '%',schema_name,'demo','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y'
FROM information_schema.schemata
WHERE NOT schema_name = 'mysql'
AND NOT schema_name = 'information_schema'
AND NOT schema_name = 'performance_schema'
AND NOT schema_name = 'id8694160_sqless';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get `Error Code: 1141. There is no such grant defined for user 'demo' on host '%'`

Comment: I've changed my answer.

Comment: *"I've changed my answer."* but don't forget to run `FLUSH  PRIVILEGES` after when manually inserting, updating or deleting privileges  from those tables..

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni Could you give me a practical example of this?

Comment: @Morgan I've added an example.